# Shopfiy sticky Div

Tags: shopify

I am using Shopify Icon theme. I need to include a sticky div to the bottom of the screen whenever someone opens on mobile. Something similar to the below image attached.

Can someone help on how to achieve that.

[sticky div example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD6rc.png)

Comment: Can you provide your attempt? A jsfiddle or a codepen would be great.

Answer (score 0):

add the css to your themes css file

```css
.sticky-div {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .sticky-div {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 10000;
    /* set height as you want */
    background: #ddd;
    /* set color as you want */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky-div">
  <!-- Your content here -->
</div>
```

Add the html before the `</body>` tag.